# Java xPath: simple expression evaluation

Tags: java, xpath

This code is using XPath to expose a library function that can check whether an XML file contains a string or an expression:

```java
    private XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    public boolean applyFilter(String xml, String xPathExpression) {
      String result = xPath.evaluate(xPathExpression, new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
      return !(StringUtils.isEmpty(result) || "false".equals(result));
    }
```

Is there a better way to do that? I'd prefer to not use external libraries here.

Comment: Somebody can explain me why has this question being downrated? Is this not the community where to ask those kind of stuff?

Comment: While I haven't down voted this question yet, I found the question in the Vote to Close queue, the reason for closing the question as off-topic is because there is no context surrounding the function. Basically there isn't enough code here to perform a good code review that points out where improvements can be made. Please see our guidelines for asking in the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: I've now read the guidelines, and I don't find a line where this question wouldn't be legitim, please show me where this question brakes guideline

Comment: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652

Comment: Sorry but no! This is Java fully working code, no pseudo code, you are here wrong!

Comment: The problem is, the code is a snippet. There is no context provided, so we can't provide a meaningful review. We need to see how the code is used, what the surroundings of the code look like, where your variables are declared. We also need to know more about the goal of the code, the current description is quite vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other said in the comments, it's a bit hard to do a code review without context; I have a suggestion for you based on the current code.

Since you seem to use the `Apache Commons - lang3` library, you can use the [`org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils#toBoolean`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toBoolean-java.lang.String-) method to convert the string boolean. This method will return false when empty or null.

**Before**

```java
public boolean applyFilter(String xml, String xPathExpression) throws XPathExpressionException {
   //[...]
   return !(StringUtils.isEmpty(result) || "false".equals(result));
}
```

**After**

```java
public boolean applyFilter(String xml, String xPathExpression) throws XPathExpressionException {
   //[...]
   return !BooleanUtils.toBoolean(result);
}
```